# Streaming with MKNetworkKit on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mknetworkkit

I'm trying to figure out how to make MKNetworkKit working with data from stream. I can see that some data is beeing downloaded (the indicator on status bar), but I don't have any idea what happens with that data after it's actually downloaded. I put a NSLog statement inside body of `connection: didReceiveData:` but it's not called during streaming. Any pointers how to fix that issue ?

**Edit**

Sorry my question was inaccurate. I know how to stream to a file but I need to stream to memory (NSData instance preferably). Okay it seems simple again due to NSOutputStream method `initWithBytes:capacity:`. And my problem is here, my stream has undefined length so there would be enormous impact on memory. I don't know what to do. My perfect solution works like this. Small chunks of data from the stream are processed having been downloaded and then they are discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `outputStreamToBuffer:capacity:` method to create the stream.

As for the buffer, you can use a circular buffer, so that you can read from it as the stream writes to it. A great implementation (and explanation) is [here](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-simple-fast-circular-buffer-implementation-for-audio-processing/).

Comment: That's what I was looking for ! thanks, a bit late, but I'm grateful !

Answer (score 0):

Streaming a file download is a three line magic with MKNetworkKit.

```
//Create a MKNetworkOperation for the remote URL.

MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithURLString:remoteURL 
                                                    params:nil
                                              httpMethod:@"GET"];

// add your output stream, in this case a file
[op addDownloadStream:[NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath
                                                             append:YES]];
// enqueue the operation to a MKNetworkEngine.
[self enqueueOperation:op];
```

That's it.

Comment: How do someone use, `[self operationWithURLString: params: httpMethod:]` method directly, I need to subclass? Any basic example for simple file download?